# Is there any way to write a test for a python grpc server with streaming responses?

Tags: python, pytest, grpc, grpc-python

There are some questions here regarding grpc testing in python, but none of them involve streaming responses. Unfortunately the grpc maintainers [are not documenting the testing API](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/17453) besides [a generic auto generated page](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc_testing.html).

Let's say there is a grpc interface like this:

```
service EchoService {
    rpc doStuff(EchoRequest) returns (stream EchoResponse) {
    }
}

message EchoRequest {
    string name = 1;
}

message EchoResponse {
    string name = 1;
}
```

With a server implementation like this:

```py
class MyServer(myservice_pb2_grpc.EchoServiceServicer):
    async def doStuff(
        self, request: myservice_pb2.EchoRequest, context: grpc.aio.ServicerContext
    ):
        yield myservice_pb2.EchoResponse(name=f"test response {request.name}")
```

How can you write a test for this server implementation?

I've tried several approaches not knowing which one could possibly work. The most promising one to me seems to be to use `pytest-grpc` using code like this:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def grpc_servicer():
    return server.MyServer()


def test_do_stuff(grpc_stub):
    request = myservice_pb2.EchoRequest(name="foo")
    response = grpc_stub.doStuff(request)
    breakpoint()
```

However here this error is returned, which seems to suggest that some grpc internal is not capable of handling async implementations:

```
Exception iterating responses: \'async_generator\' object is not an iterator"
<_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNKNOWN
    details = "Exception iterating responses: 'async_generator' object is not an iterator"
    debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer  {grpc_message:"Exception iterating responses: \'async_generator\' object is not an iterator", grpc_status:2, created_time:"2023-12-12T09:58:11.624820951+00:00"}"
```